# CD-ROM CIRC encoder

Tags: encodings

I'm studying the principles of data storage CD-ROM
At the moment I understand structures of sectors, F1 frames, F3 frames, subcode channels.
But I just can not understand the principle of forming F2 frames.

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-130.pdf

http://moais.imag.fr/membres/jean-louis.roch/perso_html/COURS/CSCI-506b-TRAIT-ERREURS/documents/IEC908.pdf

Wherever I look I do not see the implementation of this algorithm I see only a picture with a description of how. But I can not understand it.
1. What is a delay line? Is it FIFO by the required number of bytes?
2. The output data judging by the picture will appear unevenly, I correctly understand that until the first 108 frames are output, instead of some bytes, there will be garbage?
3. Can someone do or saw the implementation of this algorithm?